# Multi update not working in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which I've populated from a CSV, however there are a few fields I don't need any more in the record, so I want to remove them, but it doesn't appear to be doing anything. This is from the CLI:

```
> db.stops.update({}, { $unset: {stop_lat: 1, stop_lon: 1} }, { multi: 1 })
> db.stops.findOne({stop_id: 1000})

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50d30386884be8bf2a6c208a"),
  "stop_id" : 1000,
  // some other fields
  "stop_lat" : -27.339115,
  "stop_lon" : 153.043884,
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This may sound weird but what if you changed the `multi` value to `true` and also add `safe:true` to the options.

Comment: I tried `true` before with the same result. Adding `safe` doesn't work either.

Comment: type in mongo shell `set verbose true` and try again. after put output in question.

Comment: Hmm that is a weird one I must admit, One last ditch attempt here, add a condition like: `{stop_lat: {$ne: null}, stop_lon: {$ne: null}}` also what version of MongoDB is this?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry the verbosity didn't produce any extra output. @Sammaye I tried `{ stop_lat: {$exists: true} }` but nothing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct. The update operation in the CLI **for versions before 2.2** looks as follows :

> update(criteria, update, upsert, **multiple**)

When corrected it works :

```
> db.stops.update({}, { $unset: {stop_lat: 1, stop_lon: 1} }, false, true)
> db.stops.findOne({stop_id: 1000})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d30386884be8bf2a6c208a"), "stop_id" : 1000 }
```

EDIT : As Sammaye points out the syntax you're using is valid on the latest stable version of mongod.

Comment: Not true according to the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#crud-update-update it clearly shows `<options>` can be a single map param edit: unless he is using an old version of mongodb in which case the docs are wrong

Comment: He is. That syntax is only valid on 2.2+ iirc.

Comment: Should prolly file a JIRA for if he is, there is no mention of that on the page, hmm

Comment: hm, that's sad, that this is not commented :-(

Comment: Wow this took me a long time to find - was going nuts not understanding why the {multi: true} which is documented everywhere does not work.
Thank you so much for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using the node native driver.

`{multi:1}` does not work

`{multi:true}` does

It's weird

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this way :

CLI for versions above 2.0 looks as follows :

*update(criteria, update, upsert, multiple)*

**Example :**

*db.collectionname.update({condition},{ $set:{ groupid:'541ae260514ca0b76981222f'}},false,{ multi: true });*